# Making an invisible layer in pyQt which covers the whole dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to show a spinner while a task is being performed in my pyqt5 application. I found this nice implementation of a spinner, so I tried it: https://github.com/z3ntu/QtWaitingSpinner

The demo works ok, but in the demo the spinner is shown into an empty area of the dialog. I would like it to be an overlay which covers the whole dialog.

The author of QtWaitingSpinner suggests that "As an alternative example, the code below will create a spinner that (1) blocks all user input to the main application for as long as the spinner is active, (2) automatically centers itself on its parent widget every time "start" is called and (3) makes use of the default shape, size and color settings." with the following code:

```
spinner = QtWaitingSpinner(self, True, True, Qt.ApplicationModal)
spinner.start() # starts spinning
```

But I tried this implementation as an example, and it didn't work:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QTabWidget, QWidget, QGroupBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import requests
import urllib
from waitingspinnerwidget import QtWaitingSpinner

class DownloadDataDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DownloadDataDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.spinner = QtWaitingSpinner(self, True, True, Qt.ApplicationModal)

        tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        tabWidget.addTab(MyTab(tabWidget), "MyTab")

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Download option chain data from web")

class MyTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__(parent)

        dataGroup = QGroupBox('Data')

        getButton = QPushButton('Download')
        getButton.clicked.connect(self.download_data)

        dataLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        dataLayout.addWidget(getButton)
        dataGroup.setLayout(dataLayout)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(dataGroup)
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def download_data(self):
        self.parent().parent().parent().spinner.start()
        url = 'http://www.meff.es/docs/Ficheros/Descarga/dRV/RV180912.zip'
        filepath = None
        try:
            filepath = self.download_data_file(url)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        self.parent().parent().parent().spinner.stop()
        if filepath:
            #TODO doing stuff here
            self.parent().parent().parent().close()
        else:
            pass #TODO show error dialog

    def download_data_file(self, download_url):           
        # Build request URL and download the file
        destination = 'test.zip'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url, destination)
        return destination

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tabdialog = DownloadDataDialog()
    tabdialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So my intention is creating an invisible layer, setting the spinner as its only widget, and showing the translucid layer over the whole dialog window.

Any idea of how I should do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I also had that problem so I modified the library, first activate the flags: `QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint`, and the other change must be done in updatePosition() method:

```
def updatePosition(self):
    if self.parentWidget() and self._centerOnParent:
        parentRect = QtCore.QRect(self.parentWidget().mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)), self.parentWidget().size())
        self.move(QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.size(), parentRect).topLeft())
```

The result is as follows:

**waitingspinnerwidget.py**

```
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class QtWaitingSpinner(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, centerOnParent=True, disableParentWhenSpinning=False, modality=QtCore.Qt.NonModal):
        super().__init__(parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self._centerOnParent = centerOnParent
        self._disableParentWhenSpinning = disableParentWhenSpinning

        # WAS IN initialize()
        self._color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        self._roundness = 100.0
        self._minimumTrailOpacity = 3.14159265358979323846
        self._trailFadePercentage = 80.0
        self._revolutionsPerSecond = 1.57079632679489661923
        self._numberOfLines = 20
        self._lineLength = 10
        self._lineWidth = 2
        self._innerRadius = 10
        self._currentCounter = 0
        self._isSpinning = False

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.rotate)
        self.updateSize()
        self.updateTimer()
        self.hide()
        # END initialize()

        self.setWindowModality(modality)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        self.updatePosition()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)

        if self._currentCounter >= self._numberOfLines:
            self._currentCounter = 0

        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        for i in range(0, self._numberOfLines):
            painter.save()
            painter.translate(self._innerRadius + self._lineLength, self._innerRadius + self._lineLength)
            rotateAngle = float(360 * i) / float(self._numberOfLines)
            painter.rotate(rotateAngle)
            painter.translate(self._innerRadius, 0)
            distance = self.lineCountDistanceFromPrimary(i, self._currentCounter, self._numberOfLines)
            color = self.currentLineColor(distance, self._numberOfLines, self._trailFadePercentage,
                                          self._minimumTrailOpacity, self._color)
            painter.setBrush(color)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(QtCore.QRect(0, -self._lineWidth / 2, self._lineLength, self._lineWidth), self._roundness,
                                    self._roundness, QtCore.Qt.RelativeSize)
            painter.restore()

    def start(self):
        self.updatePosition()
        self._isSpinning = True
        self.show()

        if self.parentWidget and self._disableParentWhenSpinning:
            self.parentWidget().setEnabled(False)

        if not self._timer.isActive():
            self._timer.start()
            self._currentCounter = 0

    def stop(self):
        self._isSpinning = False
        self.hide()

        if self.parentWidget() and self._disableParentWhenSpinning:
            self.parentWidget().setEnabled(True)

        if self._timer.isActive():
            self._timer.stop()
            self._currentCounter = 0

    def setNumberOfLines(self, lines):
        self._numberOfLines = lines
        self._currentCounter = 0
        self.updateTimer()

    def setLineLength(self, length):
        self._lineLength = length
        self.updateSize()

    def setLineWidth(self, width):
        self._lineWidth = width
        self.updateSize()

    def setInnerRadius(self, radius):
        self._innerRadius = radius
        self.updateSize()

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def roundness(self):
        return self._roundness

    def minimumTrailOpacity(self):
        return self._minimumTrailOpacity

    def trailFadePercentage(self):
        return self._trailFadePercentage

    def revolutionsPersSecond(self):
        return self._revolutionsPerSecond

    def numberOfLines(self):
        return self._numberOfLines

    def lineLength(self):
        return self._lineLength

    def lineWidth(self):
        return self._lineWidth

    def innerRadius(self):
        return self._innerRadius

    def isSpinning(self):
        return self._isSpinning

    def setRoundness(self, roundness):
        self._roundness = max(0.0, min(100.0, roundness))

    def setColor(self, color=QtCore.Qt.black):
        self._color = QColor(color)

    def setRevolutionsPerSecond(self, revolutionsPerSecond):
        self._revolutionsPerSecond = revolutionsPerSecond
        self.updateTimer()

    def setTrailFadePercentage(self, trail):
        self._trailFadePercentage = trail

    def setMinimumTrailOpacity(self, minimumTrailOpacity):
        self._minimumTrailOpacity = minimumTrailOpacity

    def rotate(self):
        self._currentCounter += 1
        if self._currentCounter >= self._numberOfLines:
            self._currentCounter = 0
        self.update()

    def updateSize(self):
        size = (self._innerRadius + self._lineLength) * 2
        self.setFixedSize(size, size)

    def updateTimer(self):
        self._timer.setInterval(1000 / (self._numberOfLines * self._revolutionsPerSecond))

    def updatePosition(self):
        if self.parentWidget() and self._centerOnParent:
            parentRect = QtCore.QRect(self.parentWidget().mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)), self.parentWidget().size())
            self.move(QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.size(), parentRect).topLeft())


    def lineCountDistanceFromPrimary(self, current, primary, totalNrOfLines):
        distance = primary - current
        if distance < 0:
            distance += totalNrOfLines
        return distance

    def currentLineColor(self, countDistance, totalNrOfLines, trailFadePerc, minOpacity, colorinput):
        color = QtGui.QColor(colorinput)
        if countDistance == 0:
            return color
        minAlphaF = minOpacity / 100.0
        distanceThreshold = int(math.ceil((totalNrOfLines - 1) * trailFadePerc / 100.0))
        if countDistance > distanceThreshold:
            color.setAlphaF(minAlphaF)
        else:
            alphaDiff = color.alphaF() - minAlphaF
            gradient = alphaDiff / float(distanceThreshold + 1)
            resultAlpha = color.alphaF() - gradient * countDistance
            # If alpha is out of bounds, clip it.
            resultAlpha = min(1.0, max(0.0, resultAlpha))
            color.setAlphaF(resultAlpha)
        return color
```

With the above we solve one of those problems, the other problem is that `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` is blocking so it will cause the GUI to freeze, so the solution is to move it to another thread, using a previous response we can do it in the following way:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import urllib.request
from waitingspinnerwidget import QtWaitingSpinner


class RequestRunnable(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, url, destination, dialog):
        super(RequestRunnable, self).__init__()
        self._url = url
        self._destination = destination
        self.w = dialog

    def run(self):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self._url, self._destination)
        QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.w, "FinishedDownload", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)


class DownloadDataDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DownloadDataDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.spinner = QtWaitingSpinner(self, True, True, QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        tabWidget.addTab(MyTab(), "MyTab")
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(tabWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Download option chain data from web")


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__(parent)

        dataGroup = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Data')

        getButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Download')
        getButton.clicked.connect(self.download_data)

        dataLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        dataLayout.addWidget(getButton)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(dataGroup)
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)

    def download_data(self):
        self.parentWidget().window().spinner.start()
        url = 'http://www.meff.es/docs/Ficheros/Descarga/dRV/RV180912.zip'
        destination = 'test.zip'
        runnable = RequestRunnable(url, destination, self)
        QtCore.QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(runnable)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def FinishedDownload(self):
        self.parentWidget().window().spinner.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabdialog = DownloadDataDialog()
    tabdialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Would be great if you would PR the change to the repo, so others can benefit too.

Comment: @eyllanesc What if I need to launch an async process such as scrapy? I'm already using qt5reactor. Nevertheless, it doesn't work if done like that

Comment: Insteed of

super().__init__(parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
use

super().__init__(parent)
and at first line of the body of the init add

self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
Then you can use it in any widget.